# Reading data from Firestore database on Web app

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am so very lost on how to simply read records from Firestore.

I have a single collection called `properties`. In it, I have several documents all in the same form (all have `name`, and `category`). That's it; no subcollections or anything complex.

I have set the rules as follows (many `match`es for testing):

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read;
    
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read;
    }
  
    match /properties/{document=**} {
        allow read;
    }
    
    match /properties/{propertyid} {
        allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I have my web-based Expo app with the `firebase` npmjs package installed. I have initialized my Firebase app, and called `getFirestore` to grab a database instance and all called `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and signed in with a test account I set up in the Firebase console.

Finally, I want to grab all documents from the `properties` collection and display them on screen, so I wrote the following:

```
const query = collection(db, "properties");
const data = await getDocs(query);
```

I've also tried getting a specific property (I copied the ID from the Firebase console, so I know it exists):

```
const query = doc(db, "properties", "9sRm1TLWAIpYiZLfWPvo");
 const snapshot = await getDoc(query);
```

I am also doing the following:

1. Printing out the user credentials that I called `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. I see a large object with my `uid`, `accessToken`, etc.
2. Printing out my `db` variable (comes from `this.db = getFirestore(this.app);`). I see the correct information: firebase start options (`apiKey`, `authDomain`, `projectId`), my authentication credentials (current user `uid` matches what I see in the previous `auth` log, my `auth` object is filled out, etc. etc. (everything looks normal)

However, whatever the heck I try, I also get "Missing or insufficient permissions".

I've also checked my rules with the "Rules Playground" on any document under `/properties` and get successful simulated reads, both unauthenticated and authenticated.

What am I doing wrong and how can I just get a list of all documents in that collection? That's literally all I'm trying to do.

Comment: You mention the use of the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method. Do you want to restrict the read access to the `properties` collection only to authenticated users? Or you just want to allow anbvody to read the collection, including non authenticated users?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've tried both methods. I initially wanted authenticated users only, but nothing was working so I had tried to open it up to anyone being able to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Allow read access to all documents
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

With these rules, you're allowing read access to all documents within the Firestore database. So there won't be any need in specifying properties path in rules. Try this one and check.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I'm still receiving the permission denied error with just that single rule.

Comment: I also verified with the Rules Playground that I could access each document with this rule, both unauthenticated and authenticated